# Filter variable not working properly in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering, pandas-loc

> I have a very large dataset, and I am applying **multiple filters** on many columns. In order to make the code more readable, I **assign the filters to some variables** - but I noticed that although the values in the dataframe have changed, the filter seems like doesn't take into account the new values.

This is my dataframe:

```
data = {'id':[12, 84, 156, 228, 300, 372, 444, 516, 588, 660, 732],
       'age':['18-18', '22-22', '35-35', '33-33', '45-45', '40-40', '55-55', '60-60', '47-47', '25-25', '59-59'],
       'height':['175-177', '165-167', '175-178', '165-168', '175-179', '165-169', '175-180', '165-170', '175-181', '165-171', '175-182'],
       'weight':['65-70', '65-70', '80-85', '75-80', '90-95', '100-105', '80-85', '70-75', '70-75', '85-90', '90-95'],
       'education':['10-12', '11-13', '12-14', '13-15', '14-16', '15-17', '16-18', '17-19', '18-20', '19-21', '20-22'],
       'employment':['1-4', '8-11', '8-11', '4-7', '5-8', '5-8', '9-12', '15-18', '13-16', '12-15', '12-15'],
       'country':['France-EU', 'Austria-EU', 'Netherland-EU', 'Italy-EU', 'Texas-US', 'California-US', 'Washington-US', 'Poland-EU', 'Spain-EU', 'Greece-EU', 'New York-US'],
       'city':['Paris-FR', 'Vienna-AUS', 'Amsterdam-NL', 'Rome-ITA', 'Austin-TX', 'LA-CAL', 'Olympia-WAS', 'Warsaw-PL', 'Madrid-SPA', 'Athens-GR', 'Albany-NY']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I want to apply this filter:

```
`df['weight'] = df['weight'].astype(str)
filter1 = (df['weight'].str.slice(stop=2)=='65') & (df['country'].str.slice(stop=2)=='Au')`
```

Initially, I get what I want using the filter:

`df.loc[filter1]`

Later, I change the filtered rows as follows:

```
df.loc[filter1,'weight'] = '100'
```

And when I use again the filter I expect no result, but instead it returns me the same rows, although the value of the filter should be False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter1` doesn't magically update to match values that you set after it is created... make it again after your changes and you'll see that it works as expected:

```
def get_filter1(df):
    return df['weight'].str[:2].eq('65') & df['country'].str[:2].eq('Au')


print(df.loc[get_filter1(df)])

df.loc[get_filter1(df), 'weight'] = '100'

print(df.loc[get_filter1(df)])
```

Output:

```
   id    age   height weight education employment     country        city
1  84  22-22  165-167  65-70     11-13       8-11  Austria-EU  Vienna-AUS

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, age, height, weight, education, employment, country, city]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have many complex filters and sometimes I didn't get the same values when re-running the code which made me kind of insecure. Is there any better way to filter rather than with .loc in such cases when there are many filters in the code?

Comment: I think you should look at the output of `print(filter1)`... it's making a boolean series, not an active "filter". `loc` with a boolean mask like this is absolutely the best way to filter, but you need to use an updated mask if you expect it to give you updated values~

Comment: The active filter trick is awesome thank you :) - Then I guess I just need to practice more with the brackets on long filters when I am experiencing inconsistency. If you have any tips/article on that it would be much appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: My main piece of advice for brackets is use the `.eq` `.gt` `.le` `.ne` etc. functions rather than `==` `>` `<=` `!=`. With the former, there are fewer necessary brackets. I updated my answer to showcase this~